# Как опубликовать локальный сервер?

Tags: ip, dns, lamp

У меня есть сайт на локальном сервере с использованием LAMP стека. Как открыть доступ к этому сайту в интернете? Я настроил правила перенаправления на моем роутере. Теперь я могу увидеть сайт из локальной сети, но если я подключаюсь через 3g или другой роутер - сайт не отображается. Использовать хостинг нельзя, нужно именно открыть доступ к моему серверу. У меня динамический IP.

Comment: Недостаточно информации. Что видите вместо сайта? Какие именно правила настроили? Что указывете для подключения (имя/IP)? Какой IP указан в Apache?

Comment: @Игорь, а вы уверены, что одновременно этот IP выдан только вам? Может быть у провайдера один IP на всех, как если бы вы подключили в своей локальной сети несколько компьютеров к интернету через роутер.

Comment: Я открываю браузер на гаджете, подключенном к локальной сети. Перехожу по ссылке http://91.222.48.210 и вижу содержимое своего сайта. Но если я подключаюсь к интернету через другую сеть, я получаю ошибку ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_ERROR.

Comment: возможно это потому, что ваш роутер Очень *умный*, и поддерживает NAT loopback. В таком случае, насколько я знаю, если вы запросить свой же IP, то пакет не покинет пределов вашей внутренней сети

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Нужно убедиться, что у роутера 'белый' IP адрес на WAN интерфейсе.

Чтобы в этом убедиться нужно или самому зайти на 2ip.ru и проверить адрес.
Или спросить у провайдера.

Небольшое пояснение. 2ip.ru покажет или Ваш внешний адрес, или внешний адрес провайдера. Сравниваете его с тем, что в бумажке по настройке провайдера. Или в настройках роутера.
Если адреса разные - повод задуматься.

Если адрес WAN у Вас 'серый' (напр., из сетей 192.168.*.* или 10.*.*.*), то нужно уточнить имеется ли у провайдера вообще опция подключения 'внешнего' адреса. Обычно это делается за отдельные деньги, если это вообще возможно.

2. Если у Вас динамический 'белый' IP адрес, то можно его привязать к доменному имени, чтобы всегда иметь по нему доступ снаружи. Иначе каждый раз угадывать адрес будет муторно. См. в сторону сервисов типа dyndns
3. Обязательно нужно настроить т.н. port forwarding на роутере. В разных роутерах и даже разных версиях прошивок к одной железке эти настройки могут быть в разных местах.
4. Отключите для теста файрволл на компьютере. Или настройте его на прием входящих соединений по необходимым портам.

*Дополнительно*. Иногда бывает, что интернет подключен не через роутер напрямую, а стоит какое-либо дополнительное оборудование. Например, adsl-модем, кабельный модем (вроде Arris, который выдает Ростелеком) или что еще. Так вот. Это оборудование тоже нуждается в настройке. У меня интернет приходит через PON-терминал и в нем настройки закрыты вообще. Поэтому опубликовать сервер по-простому дома нельзя. Ну, и использовать двойной NAT это тоже идея не лучшая (а так действительно может случиться, т.к. и роутер, и модем умеют подключенным устройствам раздавать локальные адреса)

*Дополнение 2* Можно заморочиться и сделать домой доступ по протоколу ipv6. Это здоровская идея, но все упирается в то есть ли ее поддержка в роутере и у провайдера. Если нет - существуют специальные сервисы, туннельные брокеры, которые могут с этим помочь. Правда, это точно не для новичка.

Если нужны более конкретные инструкции - дайте, пожалуйста, больше информации об адресах, оборудовании и софту

Comment: жирный минус, для того что бы узнать адрес не нужно ходить к             провайдеру или вообще куда то, достаточно ввести одну команду из    консоли

Comment: @maint вот знаете - хочется ругаться ))) насчет консоли Вы не правы - на домашних роутерах ее тупо нет, есть только веб-интерфейс. Действительно же, обычно IP адрес можно в нем посмотреть, но если провайдер идиот и предоставляет интернет по какому-нибудь pppoe, то адрес будет динамикой и спрятан где-то в доп.настройках или диагностике, что опять же в разных моделях ищется по-разному. А ipconfig на компьютере делу не поможет

Comment: Дополнительно - если пробуете слить мне рейт, минусуя другие ответы, то сообщаю, что это плохая идея. За Вами следит большой Брат )))

Answer (score 0):

все что требуется, это заключить с провайдером договор о статическом IP адресе (или доп.услуга). Стоит около 100 руб в месяц, чаще даже меньше. Ну и настроить DNS свой или  через yandex, google. Плюс доменное имя зарегистрировать (от 400 руб в год), там же можно и DNS настроить, как у меня в мастерхост

Comment: На самом деле, мне необходимо только на короткое время подключиться к серверу. Почему я не могу сделать это, используя динамический IP?

Comment: пробейте порты по этому адресу снаружи. Когда я смотрел по nmap но увидел открытым только один порт 443, да и тот не работает путем

Comment: Действительно, что-то странное с портами. В apache2 как обычно указано Listen 80 и Listen 443. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: файерволом закрыты порты могут быть, например.

Comment: У меня стоит Ubuntu Studio, firewall по умолчанию должен быть отключен.

Comment: *Жирный минус*. Статический ай пи адрес не при делах. Можно и по динамическому зайти. Главное, чтобы он был не 'серый'